# Is there any way to remove an Accepted Version from WFS in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I am trying to remove accepted versions on my WFS services in GeoServer(v2.19.0).
Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think you can, the question is why would you want to?

Comment: It is not uncommon with INSPIRE services to support only WFS 2.0 which is the required version. For example this one from France accepts only 2.0 (see the returned GetCapabilities) http://wxs.ign.fr/inspire/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Comment: So what, supporting more than the bare minimum is never a bad thing

Comment: Restricting number of endpoints for the services, if I only need one version looking to disable the others. No real reason other than wanting to.

Comment: removing accepted versions from your service doesn't remove endpoints, it's the same endpoint that returns different versions.